# How to use Dependency Injection in a class library?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I have installed the Microsoft Dependency Injection into a .NET Framework 4.8 class library. I have also reigster interface A to class A. The problem is that my class B that takes a object of interface A in construtor still demands it when I try to create the class? So how do I get the DI system to provide this object in a class Library where there is no real entry point?

```
public Class B
{
   B(){InterfaceA}
}

public Class A : InterfaceA
{}

public MainClass
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
       DependencyContainer.Register();
       var myB = new B();
    }
}

public DependencyContainer
{
     public void Register()
     {
         (new ServiceCollection()).AddTransient<InterfaceA, A>();
     }
}
```

Regards

Comment: You need to register ClassA as InterfaceA with the container. Unfortuantely I'm not familiar with Microsoft Dependency Injection, so I can't say how to do this.

Comment: Yes, i missed the DependencyContainer.Register() in my example but it have been added now. B do still need the object of InterfaceA however.

Comment: Don't you have to tell the container how to register ClassA? Does Register just scan your application for types or something? Do you have a documentation link because I just can't find it.

Comment: Aha, yes thats what happens in the Register methdo, I have no added that as well.

Comment: Oh this is the container that came with ASP.NET Core. OK now I get it.

Comment: Instead of using that `DependencyContainer` class do the same thing ASP.NET Core and all NuGet packages do - create an extension method called `AddMyAwesomeProject` on `IServicesCollection` and register your classes there. Call that method either in your `Startup` class (for web apps) or `ConfigureServices` delegate (for console, service apps and Blazor)

Comment: To be able to successfully answer the question we need to know whether the class library is (a) a reusable library that is distributed through a mechanism such as NuGet and reused by solutions outside your control, or (b) a library that is solely used as part of a single solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DI means that any depencencies will come (get injected) from the outside. The class itself won't even know that dependency injection is used. In your case, the classes should be rewritten to accept dependencies instead of creating them:

```
public Class B
{
   public A MyA {get;}

   public B(InterfaceA a)
   {
      MyA=a;
   }
}

public Class A : InterfaceA
{}

public MainClass
{
    public B MyB {get;}
    public MainClass(B b)
    {
        MyB=b;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
       MyB......;
    }
}
```

The classes know nothing about DI. When asked for a `MainClass` instance with, eg `services.GetRequiredService<MyClass>()`, the DI container will create all the necessary instances and pass them to the classes.

The common pattern for all .NET Core libraries is to provide extension methods that can be used to register or configure their classes in the main application's `Startup` class or `ConfigureServices` delegate. To do that, all that's needed is the `IServicesCollection` interface from the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` package. There's no need to add the full DI package :

```
public static class MyLibServiceExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyClasses(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ClassB>()
                .AddTransient<InterfaceA,ClassA>()
                .AddTransient<MainClass>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

This can be used now to register the classes, eg in a Console application :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddMyClasses()
                        .AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

Or the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method of a web app:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        HostingEnvironment = env;
    }

    public IWebHostEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.AddMyClasses();
    }
}
```

The classes will now be injected into any class generated by the DI container, eg a `Controller:

```
public class MyController:ControllerBase
{
    public MyController(MyDbContext dbContext,MainClass main)
    {
        _db=dbContext;
        _main=main;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so dependency injection isn't magic. Your `Register` method is building a collection of services and throwing it away. You need to actually resolve your components from the container (I'm not saying directly, but the container has to be involved).

You should build an `IServiceProvider` from it using the [`BuildServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectioncontainerbuilderextensions.buildserviceprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) method:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddTransient<InterfaceA, A>();
serviceCollection.AddTransient<B>();
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var b = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<B>(); // constructs B and injects A
```

Probably you should do this in your Main method, and then inject B (or a Func to create B) into `MainClass`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<MainClass>();
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<InterfaceA, A>();
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<B>();
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<Func<B>>(provider => () => provider.GetRequiredService<B>()); // factory method
    var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    // ask the container for MainClass and then call DoStuff
    var mainClass = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainClass>();
    mainClass.DoStuff();
}
```

And then you could rewrite MainClass like this:

```
public class MainClass
{
    private readonly B _bInstance;
    private readonly Func<B> _bFactory = new Func<B>();
    
    // if you want to create instances of B as and when, I'd suggest using a factory
    // otherwise you can pass in a single instance
    // I've done both here as an example
    public MainClass(Func<B> bFactory, B bInstance)
    {
        _bInstance = bInstance;
        _bFactory = bFactory;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // create two instances of B
        var b1 = _bFactory();
        var b2 = _bFactory();
    }
}
```

While I advocate for using a factory when you need to build instances on the fly, it is possible to inject `IServiceProvider` itself into your classes, and then call its `GetRequiredService` or `GetService` methods. The reason I don't do this is because it is [considered to be an anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Using a factory allows you to still make changes at the composition root (i.e. in `Main`) without editing everywhere that creates instances of `B`.